# Enable pop up login page to user if meet auth error in WebAuth BrowserAuth package

Tags: msal.js

**Name of Team Making the Request: **
Loop In Word
**Engineering Contact Alias:**
sunyao
**Target Release: Month: **
Sep.
**Why Needed/Impact: **
For loop in word feature which leverage WebAuth BrowserAuth package to get token, we encounter some auth issue which impact our reliability as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6wIS.png)

We want to use prompt to resolve the auth* failure rate for these type of issues. However,currently pop up in WebAuth BrowserAuth package could only resolve "AADSTS50058" error, could we also support using pop up login page to resolve other auth issues? This is a ship blocker for loop on WO right now.

Enable pop up login page to user if meet auth error in WebAuth BrowserAuth package